# Pass data from input field into variable without submitting

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Trying to get my head around react. I want to take data from an input field and pass it into a variable (let) so I can then pass it back into the html in a separate string. Would this be 'two way binding'? Does anyone have a simple example of this working?

http://codepen.io/IanHazelton/pen/ygEomV?editors=0110

```
let name="{name from input}";
let age="{age from input}";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className ="wrap">
          <h1 className="string">What's your name?</h1>
          <input type="text" id="name" />
          <h1 className="string">How old are you?</h1>
          <input type="text" id="age" />
          <h1 className="string">Hi {name}! How are you today? You're {age} years old.</h1>
       </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('Root'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take advantage of the `state` of the component. I modified your pen to work with the `name` property, you can do the same to your other inputs:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
  }

  handleNameOnChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className="wrap">
          <h1 className="string">What's your name?</h1>
          <input type="text" id="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={ (e) => this.handleNameOnChange(e) } />
          <h1 className="string">How old are you?</h1>
          <input type="text" id="age" />
          <h1 className="string">Hi {this.state.name}! How are you today? You're {age} years old.</h1>
       </div>
    )

  }
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/OmriAharon/pen/XpYVMK?editors=0110)

Comment: Works! Thanks for the friendly, informative and effective reply!

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to use `state` in App component, Concept is whenever user provide any input in the `fields`, store those values in `state` variable, And whenever you make any change in `state` values, `React` will `render` whole `component` again, try this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={name: '', age: ''}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className ="wrap">
          <h1 className="string">What's your name?</h1>
          <input value={this.state.name} type="text" id="name" onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({name: e.target.value})}}/>
          <h1 className="string">How old are you?</h1>
          <input  value={this.state.age} onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({age: e.target.value})}} type="text" id="age" />
          <h1 className="string">Hi {this.state.name}! How are you today? You're {this.state.age} years old.</h1>
       </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('Root'))
```

Check the working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egKyvJ?editors=0110

Comment: Works! Thanks for the friendly, informative and effective reply!